# Unable to load the web View Android Studios

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

There is an error in the webview part. Please help me out. Following the tutorial here I have set up an app that should be able to open a URL and place it into an WebView. The only issue is that the app stops while running in emulator.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;

`enter code here`public class WebViewActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view1);
        wv1=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv1.loadUrl("http://www.medplusmart.com/");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_web_view_activity1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First**  - In your question please provide to developers your logCat.

**Second** - you have bug in your code look at this image why there is `'enter here your code'`

**before** `public class WebViewActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity`

[image]

hope it's help :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have declared required permissions in your manifest file

```
[your-proj\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml]:



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your-package">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    ...
    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```